# Finding expected value of diamonds given no spades are selected

Tags: probability

We have 10 cards in a box. They are: 2 diamonds, 3 spades, and 5 hearts. Select without replacement 2 cards. Calculate the expected number of diamonds selected given that no spade is selected.

attempt

Let $X$ be the number of diamonds in two cards chosen. We have

$$ P(X=0) = \frac{8}{10} = \frac{4}{5} $$

$$ P(X=1) = \frac{2}{10} \cdot \frac{8}{9} = \frac{8}{45}$$

$$ P(X=2) = \frac{2}{10} = \frac{1}{5} $$

Now, we call $Y$ to be the number of spades. We have

$$ P(Y=0) = \frac{7}{10} $$

We want find $E(X|Y=0)$. So we have

$$ E(X|Y=0) = \sum_{x=0}^2\frac{x  p_{XY}(x,0)}{p_Y(0)} = \frac{10}{7} \left( 1 \cdot p_{XY}(1,0) + 2 p_{XY}(2,0)\right)$$

now,

$$ p_{XY}(1,0) = P(X=1 \cap Y=0) = \frac{2}{10} \frac{5}{9} = \frac{1}{9} $$

and

$$ p_{XY}(2,0) = P(X=2) = \frac{1}{5} $$

hence,

$$E(X|Y=0) = \frac{10}{7} \left( \frac{1}{9} + \frac{2}{5} \right) = \frac{46}{63} $$

Is this a correct solution?

Comment: Seems like a lot of work.  Since we know that no spades were selected, just ignore them and work with the remaining cards.

Comment: Hint (two methods):  method I (brute force):  there are only $21$ pairs with no spades, just list them all and do it by hand.  method II (indicator variables).  let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ diamond and then the answer is $E[X_1+X_2]=2\times E[X_1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Your evaluations are way off.

$P(X=0)=\dfrac{8\cdot 7}{10\cdot 9}$ is the probability that *neither* from the two cards selected is a diamond.

$P(X=1)=2\cdot\dfrac{2\cdot 8}{10\cdot 9}$ is the probability that one card is a diamond (first *xor* second drawn).

$P(X=2)=\dfrac{2\cdot 1}{10\cdot 9}$ is the probability that *both* cards are diamonds.

$P(Y=0)= \dfrac{7\cdot 6}{10\cdot 9}$ is the probability that *neither* from the two cards is a spade.

$P(X=0, Y=0)= \dfrac{5\cdot 4}{10\cdot 9}$ is the probability that *neither* card is a spade or diamond (ie both are hearts)

$P(X=1, Y=0)= 2\cdot\dfrac{2\cdot 5}{10\cdot 9}$ is the probability that one card is a diamond and the other a heart (and so neither is a spade)

$P(X=2, Y=0)= \dfrac{2\cdot 1}{10\cdot 9}$ is the probability that both cards are diamonds (and so neither is a spade) as previously established.

Think about why.

---

However, there is a much easier method.  Lay the cards face down on the table.   Under the condition that neither is a spade, what is the expectation that the left-most card is a diamond?   Likewise what is that of the right-most card?   Use the *Linearity of Expectation* to determine the expected count for diamonds among the two cards under given condition.